# Twitter bootstrap modal animation on close

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, hide, modal-dialog, css-transitions

I am trying to add animation to bootstraps modal using animate.less library.

The animation is working completely when it is to show the modal. But on hide of the modal the animation is not working. I have created a jsfiddle to replicate the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/W6G4q/1/

```
<a href="#" role="button" class="letclick btn btn-warning" id='loginLink' targetLink="login">     
        <i class="icon-user icon-white"></i>
        Sign In
    </a>
    <div class="modal hide login-modal animated bounceOutRight" tabindex="-1"  aria-labelledby="LoginModal" aria-hidden="true" id="login" >
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Ã—</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Login</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

 SHOWING
</div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
     $('#loginLink').click(function(){
        $('#login').modal({
        backdrop: true,
        keyboard: true
    }).css({
        'width': function () {
            return (350) + 'px'; 
        },
        'margin-left': function () {
            return -($(this).width() / 2);
        }
    });

        $('#login').toggleClass('bounceInLeft bounceOutRight')
    });
     $('#login').on('hide', function(){

        $(this).toggleClass('bounceOutRight bounceInLeft');


    });
```

bounceOutRight and bounceInLeft are working properly and are css based animations provided by the library animate.less

I am sure im not calling hide correctly, maybe hide is putting in the hidden class before the animation. Im not sure, any help would be great.

JS fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/W6G4q/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a jQuery or Bootstrap Ninja but I tried to do a workaround and it seems to be working:

http://jsfiddle.net/DrCtZ/

HTML

```
<a href="#!" role="button" class="btn btn-warning" id='loginLink'>     
   <i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Sign In
</a>

<div class="modal hide animated bounceInRight" id="login" >
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Login</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        SHOWING
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#loginLink').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            $('#login').on('hide', function(e) {
                if($('#login').hasClass('bounceInRight'))
                {   e.preventDefault();

                $('#login').removeClass('bounceInRight').addClass('bounceOutRight');

                setTimeout("$('#login').modal('hide')", 550);}
            });

            $('#login').modal('show');
        });
    });
```

Short explication :
In fact modal is shown manually. Then, on hidden you prevent action to change class as you want and after this you manually close the modal.
setTimeout is here because bounce animation is longer than the default one...

Added the if braces and works perfectly

Comment: It hangs after the first time. Its recursing when its called again. But that timeout thing does help out. thanks

Comment: just to point out, have to include removeclass and settimeout lines inside the if statement.